# Run-time Error: WordBasic Commands are not available for reading

Tags: vba, ms-word, runtime-error, word-2013

I have a macro which has following calls of Wordbasic:

```
    WordBasic.StartOfDocument

    WordBasic.SetDocumentDirty 0

    WordBasic.SetTemplateDirty 0
```

When I run the code, it gives run time error:- These commands are not available for reading in word 2013. Whereas it is running fine with other versions of Word. 
There are lots of calls of WordBasic but I have changed them with ActiveDocument calls.

Is there any way to change these calls with ActiveDocument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
ActiveDocument.Saved = False
ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate.Saved = False
```

In addition, in Word 2013 the documents are opened in Reading View by default. In that case, you may need to allow editing the document by setting

```
ActiveWindow.View.ReadingLayout = False
```

Comment: thanks a lot for input. I have changed my code with this but I am getting error In Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory , Its showing runtime error 4605: this command is unavailable for reading. When I comment this line then rest of two are running fine. I am a beginner in this So unable to understand the prob. Kindly help!!!

Comment: @Iari: I applied the edits you proposed (with minor variations) as they seemed perfectly reasonable to me. I will delete this comment soon.